# How to make a form responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a contact form, I tried to make it responsive but I am stuck. I have tried with css but it's still not responsive.  Even `panel panel-heading` also looks awkward in my responsive mode. I tried to put a toggle on navbar to make it collapse but it's not working. I have imported external bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in my code. please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
<style>
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
 face: Calibri;
}
.panel-footer {
    padding: 20px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 height: 80px !important;
 }
 .close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 31px;
 margin-left: 22px;
 color: black;
 
 
 }
 button.close {
    padding: 1;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
 font-weight: 700px
 background-color: black;
   }
   .underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  .form-control{
  border-color: blue;
  }
  .panel-default {
    border-color: black;
}
}
</style>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container ">
        <a href="# " class="navbar-brand ">
  <img src="logo1.jpg " height="48 " width="202 " class="pull-left "></a>
 <center> <p class="navbar-text ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" ">Ticker </a></p></center>
<p class="navbar-text pull-left ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" " ></a></p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right "><a href=" ">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br />
<div class="container ">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
<h4 id="main " style='color: #4CAEE3';><a href="ht.html ">HT</a> /<a href="createemployee.html ">Create </a></h4><br />
</div>
</div>
 <br />
<form class="form-horizontal " id="myform ">
 <h4 ><center><a href="createem.html "><font style="color: #0000ff;font-weight: 700; face: Calibri; ">New </font></a></center></h4>
 
  <form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
 <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal ">
 <font color="black ">  <a href="hrtoolkit.html ">
  <span  class="underline " id="u ">&times;</span></a></font>     </button>
<div class="form-body ">
  <br />
  <div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "> ID<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="emp " required placeholder="if " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'ID Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">First Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="fname " required placeholder="First Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'First Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Gender<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">

                                        <select class="form-control " required placeholder="Gender " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Gender Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
          
                                                <option hidden value=" ">Gender</option>
                                                <option value="male ">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female ">Female</option>
                                                <option value="other ">Other</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOJ<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="doj " required placeholder="DOJ " required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOJ Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="font-weight: 700; ">eMail</span><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="email " class="form-control " id="eMail " pattern="^[\w.+\-]+@infinitumglobal\.com$ " required placeholder="eMail " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(
    'Email ID Required format example@infinitumglobal.com') "
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Middle Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="mname " placeholder="Middle Name ">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOB<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="dob " required placeholder="DOB "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOB Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="desg " required placeholder="Designation "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Designation Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Last Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="lname " required placeholder="Last Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Last Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

       <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          


                                    <div class="panel-footer text-right ">
                                        <button type="submit " id="btnSave " class="btn btn-default pull-right " style="background-color: #90EE90; ">Save</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </form>



    </form>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: You can see here gap between email and middle name and text box attached with panel]

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: it is already reponsive.Then what is ur problem  here

Comment: @RamlalS see my answer I added required urls

Comment: Form is not in mobile responsive the text fields are attached with panel and between text boxes much gap in mobile responsive.

Comment: so dont use `col-md-4` change it to `col-sm-4` what mean small size

Comment: I recommand you follow the link that I attach to my answer and learn about bootstrap responsive

Comment: Please help anybody..

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `script` that I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look here:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
<style>
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
 face: Calibri;
}
.panel-footer {
    padding: 20px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 height: 80px !important;
 }
 .close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 31px;
 margin-left: 22px;
 color: black;
 
 
 }
 button.close {
    padding: 1;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
 font-weight: 700px
 background-color: black;
   }
   .underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  .form-control{
  border-color: blue;
  }
  .panel-default {
    border-color: black;
}
}
</style>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container ">
        <a href="# " class="navbar-brand ">
  <img src="logo1.jpg " height="48 " width="202 " class="pull-left "></a>
 <center> <p class="navbar-text ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" ">Ticker </a></p></center>
<p class="navbar-text pull-left ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" " ></a></p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right "><a href=" ">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br />
<div class="container ">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
<h4 id="main " style='color: #4CAEE3';><a href="ht.html ">HT</a> /<a href="createemployee.html ">Create </a></h4><br />
</div>
</div>
 <br />
<form class="form-horizontal " id="myform ">
 <h4 ><center><a href="createem.html "><font style="color: #0000ff;font-weight: 700; face: Calibri; ">New </font></a></center></h4>
 
  <form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
 <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal ">
 <font color="black ">  <a href="hrtoolkit.html ">
  <span  class="underline " id="u ">&times;</span></a></font>     </button>
<div class="form-body ">
  <br />
  <div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "> ID<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="emp " required placeholder="if " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'ID Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">First Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="fname " required placeholder="First Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'First Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Gender<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">

                                        <select class="form-control " required placeholder="Gender " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Gender Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
          
                                                <option hidden value=" ">Gender</option>
                                                <option value="male ">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female ">Female</option>
                                                <option value="other ">Other</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOJ<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="doj " required placeholder="DOJ " required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOJ Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="font-weight: 700; ">eMail</span><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="email " class="form-control " id="eMail " pattern="^[\w.+\-]+@infinitumglobal\.com$ " required placeholder="eMail " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(
    'Email ID Required format example@infinitumglobal.com') "
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Middle Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="mname " placeholder="Middle Name ">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOB<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="dob " required placeholder="DOB "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOB Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="desg " required placeholder="Designation "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Designation Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Last Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="lname " required placeholder="Last Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Last Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

       <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          


                                    <div class="panel-footer text-right ">
                                        <button type="submit " id="btnSave " class="btn btn-default pull-right " style="background-color: #90EE90; ">Save</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </form>



    </form>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: I have attached the image. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
<style>
.form-group{
padding: 15px;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
 face: Calibri;
}
.panel-footer {
    padding: 20px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 height: 80px !important;
 }
 .close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 31px;
 margin-left: 22px;
 color: black;
 
 
 }
 button.close {
    padding: 1;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
 font-weight: 700px
 background-color: black;
   }
   .underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  .form-control{
  border-color: blue;
  }
  .panel-default {
    border-color: black;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ">
  <img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" height="30" width="202" class="pull-left "></a>
 <center> <p class="navbar-text pull-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Ticker </a></p></center>
<p class="navbar-text pull-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" >Banner</a></p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right"><a href="">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br />
<div class="container ">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
<h4 id="main " style='color: #4CAEE3';><a href="ht.html ">HT</a> /<a href="createemployee.html ">Create </a></h4><br />
</div>
</div>
 <br />
<form class="form-horizontal " id="myform ">
 <h4 ><center><a href="createem.html "><font style="color: #0000ff;font-weight: 700; face: Calibri; ">New </font></a></center></h4>
 
  <form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
 <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal ">
 <font color="black ">  <a href="hrtoolkit.html ">
  <span  class="underline " id="u ">&times;</span></a></font>     </button>
<div class="form-body ">
  <br />
  <div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "> ID<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="emp " required placeholder="if " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'ID Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">First Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="fname " required placeholder="First Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'First Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Gender<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">

                                        <select class="form-control " required placeholder="Gender " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Gender Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
          
                                                <option hidden value=" ">Gender</option>
                                                <option value="male ">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female ">Female</option>
                                                <option value="other ">Other</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOJ<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="doj " required placeholder="DOJ " required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOJ Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="font-weight: 700; ">eMail</span><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="email " class="form-control " id="eMail " pattern="^[\w.+\-]+@infinitumglobal\.com$ " required placeholder="eMail " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(
    'Email ID Required format example@infinitumglobal.com') "
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Middle Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="mname " placeholder="Middle Name ">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOB<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="dob " required placeholder="DOB "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOB Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="desg " required placeholder="Designation "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Designation Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Last Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="lname " required placeholder="Last Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Last Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

       <div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          


                                    <div class="panel-footer text-right ">
                                        <button type="submit " id="btnSave " class="btn btn-lg pull-right " style="background-color: #90EE90; ">Save</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </form>



    </form>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
<style>
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
 face: Calibri;
}
.panel-footer {
    padding: 20px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 height: 80px !important;
 }
 .close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 31px;
 margin-left: 22px;
 color: black;
 
 
 }
 button.close {
    padding: 1;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
 font-weight: 700px
 background-color: black;
   }
   .underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  .form-control{
  border-color: blue;
  }
  .panel-default {
    border-color: black;
}
}
</style>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container ">
        <a href="# " class="navbar-brand ">
  <img src="logo1.jpg " height="48 " width="202 " class="pull-left "></a>
 <center> <p class="navbar-text ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" ">Ticker </a></p></center>
<p class="navbar-text pull-left ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" " ></a></p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right "><a href=" ">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br />
<div class="container ">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
<h4 id="main " style='color: #4CAEE3';><a href="ht.html ">HT</a> /<a href="createemployee.html ">Create </a></h4><br />
</div>
</div>
 <br />
<form class="form-horizontal " id="myform ">
 <h4 ><center><a href="createem.html "><font style="color: #0000ff;font-weight: 700; face: Calibri; ">New </font></a></center></h4>
 
  <form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
 <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal ">
 <font color="black ">  <a href="hrtoolkit.html ">
  <span  class="underline " id="u ">&times;</span></a></font>     </button>
<div class="form-body ">
  <br />
  <div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "> ID<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="emp " required placeholder="if " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'ID Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">First Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="fname " required placeholder="First Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'First Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Gender<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">

                                        <select class="form-control " required placeholder="Gender " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Gender Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
          
                                                <option hidden value=" ">Gender</option>
                                                <option value="male ">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female ">Female</option>
                                                <option value="other ">Other</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOJ<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="doj " required placeholder="DOJ " required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOJ Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="font-weight: 700; ">eMail</span><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="email " class="form-control " id="eMail " pattern="^[\w.+\-]+@infinitumglobal\.com$ " required placeholder="eMail " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(
    'Email ID Required format example@infinitumglobal.com') "
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <!--<div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Middle Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="mname " placeholder="Middle Name ">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">DOB<span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="date " class="form-control " id="dob " required placeholder="DOB "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'DOB Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 "><span style="color: red; ">*</span> </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="desg " required placeholder="Designation "  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Designation Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4 ">

                            <!--<div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->

                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">Last Name<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="lname " required placeholder="Last Name " oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity( 'Last Name Required') " oninput="this.setCustomValidity( '') "  />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

       <!--<div class="row " style="visibility: hidden ">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 ">res<span style="color: red; ">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 ">
                                        <input type="text " class="form-control " id="formGroupExampleInput2 ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->

                          


                                    <div class="panel-footer text-right ">
                                        <button type="submit " id="btnSave " class="btn btn-default pull-right " style="background-color: #90EE90; ">Save</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </form>



    </form>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue was with "row" which you have added with style= "visibility: hidden". Use "display" property of CSS to show/hide any component in HTML. Visibility CSS property hides the visibility of HTML tag but the area covered by component still remains as it is.

I have added all such "row" in comments and the issue was resolved. Hope this helps you.